# Error in for each loop vb.net razor 2 (ASP.NET web pages)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

I have this error in my vb.net razor 2 code "Object variable or With block variable not set." Line 11

```
   Line 9:      Dim i = 0
   Line 10:         
   Line 11:     @For Each color In PageData("Colors")
   Line 12:         @<p style="background-color:@color; font-family:@Page.Fonts(i)">
   Line 13:             This paragraph is @color
```

This is my _PageStart.vbhtml Code:

```
   @Code
       Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout1.vbhtml"
       PageData("Colors") = {"LightCyan", "Gainsboro", "Chocolate"}
   End Code
```

This is my default.vbhtml code:

```
   @Code
       Page.Title = "Level 1 Start page"
       Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout2.vbhtml"
   End Code

   <h1>Testing _PageStart From Level 1</h1>

   @Code
       Dim i = 0

       @For Each color In PageData("Colors")
           @<p style="background-color:@color; font-family:@Page.Fonts(i)">
               This paragraph is @color 
           </p>
           i += 1
       Next

   End Code

   <p><a href="/Level1/Page">Click</a> to visit Level 1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shown, you do not appear to have initialised Page.Fonts which is covered in Step 10 of the relevant Try It Out in the book you are using. Here's a VB version:

```
Page.Fonts = {"Verdana", "Arial", "Courier New"}
```